# Installed MacOS Ventura in a wrong nested volume. How to put it back to the root?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, disk-volume

I erased "Macintosh" and "Macintosh - Data" volumes and had a mistake installing Ventura in "Macintosh" volume instead of the root. The OS is now located in the nested place as seen in the Disk Utility screenshot. Is there a way to move all to the correct place?
The output of `diskutil list` is as follows:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         500.0 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +500.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh - Data        704.5 KB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 1.9 GB     disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                1.2 GB     disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume Macintosh - Data        109.3 GB   disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume Macintosh               9.2 GB     disk1s6
   6:              APFS Snapshot com.apple.os.update-... 9.2 GB     disk1s6s1
   7:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 MB     disk1s7
```

[image: Disk Utility Screenshot]

I erased the whole partition and erased with the journalized format. The new setting is still with the nested pattern:
[image: my mac disk pattern]
But I want that to be as this (took from another mac):
[image]

Comment: Try `diskutil apfs deletevolume disk1s1`.

Comment: So this will only delete the Data volume, but how about moving macintosh\everything (mac and macData) to \everything?
However I realized the faster solution is to reinstall macos

Comment: Other than having two `Macintosh - Data` volumes, everything else looks correct. What else do you specially see as incorrect?

Comment: I want to remove the nested pattern. I erased the whole setting journalized format. but it is not solved. I add screenshot to my question

Comment: That's just how it is these days - https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWiO6.png

Comment: @Tetsujin: Is that image Ventura? Is the image Intel? I am guessing Monterey on Apple Silicon.

Comment: @DavidAnderson -  Ventura, M1 iMac.